# Java, Hibernate annotations, How to add methods to POJO object?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, pojo

I am using hibernate annotations. How to add methods to POJO object? For example i have "getChildNodes" method, associated with database, but i want also add recursive method "getAllChildNodes". I get "org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a setter for property progress in class" exception when i do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I interpret this as "how do I add a method that is NOT related to persistence" then you need to use the `@Transient` annotation on the `getAllChildNodes()` method

Comment: I'm confused. Doesn't adding extra functionality such as getAllChildNodes(), or publish() for example, make it not a POJO anymore? And therefore violates a design principle of hibernate objects having to be POJO's and is therefore "bad"? But why would it be bad? I want to do this but I'm not sure if it's the right way.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of defining the structure of your entity.

- using annotations on the instance variables of your entity or
- using annotations on the getter methods of your entity

When using the annotations on getter methods, Hibernate assumes that every getXxx (and isXxx for boolean types) represents definition of a persistent property. And this holds even if that particular getter does not contain any annotations, as happens in your case.

Hibernate also expects to find a matching setter method for each persistent property. And in your case that is what's missing and causes the exception.

You can solve this problem by declaring your custom getter as `@Transient` that says this getter does not represent a persistent property. Another way would be to convert the entity to use annotations on the instance variables. The latter would be my personal choice.

Answer (score -1):

Open up the .java file and write a method named `getAllChildNodes()`.

Hibernate doesn't write code for you, it maps fields in your database to your code. That's all. If you want to have extra logic in your domain/model classes besides the normal getters and setters for your properties, you'll have to add them yourself.